# Cómo puedo cambiar el valor de una variable al dar click con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

No sé si es posible, pero lo que quisiera hacer es que al dar click a un botón por ejemplo, pueda cambiar el valor de una variable por ejemplo, pero que el valor de esta variable pueda ser usado fuera de la función click.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a">Botón</button>
<div id="div"></div>
<script>

//Esto es sólo un ejemplo a medias
var v = 0;

$('#id').click(function(){
  var v = 1;
});
$('#div').html(v);
</script>
```

Según este ejemplo lo que quisiera hacer es que al dar al botón, el valor de la variable que está dentro de la función permanezca para luego ser mostrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que es posible. Solo asegúrate de colocar las partes correctas entre las funciones que vas a asignar los valores y a los eventos de tus elementos, como tus click, hovers, etc..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a">Botón</button>
<div id="div"></div>
<script>

//Esto es sólo un ejemplo a medias
var v = 0;
setValor();
$('#a').click(function(){
  v++;
  setValor();
});
function setValor(){
  $('#div').html(v);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el ejemplo, me quedó claro. Después de todo era bastante simple xd.

Answer (score 0):

Esta bien lo que hiciste, lo único que debes cambiar es que no declares la variable dos veces y ejecutes tu evento **click** con el id correcto, mira:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="id">Botón</button>
<div id="div"></div>
<script>

//Esto es sólo un ejemplo a medias
var v = 0;

$('#id').click(function(){
  v = 1;
 $("#div").html(v);
});
</script>
```